# css works on input text not text area

Tags: html, css

This is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2GpmW/

when I set the css, I did this:

```
.inputForm input[type="text"], .inputForm input[type="email"], .inputForm textarea, .inputForm select {
    border: none;
    color: #525252;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 5px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    background: #DFDFDF;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

so as you see the css show be applied to both input text and text area but for some reasons, the label beside the text area becomes down and place holder inside the text area is not centered vertically as it is in the input text

please :

1- why is that happening?

2- how to solve it

Many thanks

Comment: The issue is because your elements are inline, you can try `display:block` on your labels but you are probably going to get issues crossbrower. A better approach might be to contain your form elements in divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
textarea{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GpmW/4/)

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell element.

Comment: `vertical-align: top` more closely matches the other two label's vertical positioning.

Comment: thanks but your jsfiddle is exactly as mine, nothing has changed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish true :)

Comment: +1 for your efforts. many thanks, will accept it when the system allows

Comment: Just checked in all major browsers and it fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add vertical-align:middle to both textarea and label.

```
label, textarea{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: But not `!important`, which should be used almost never.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I agree, It is important to never use `important` in css :)

Comment: +1 for your efforts. however the other guy answered first so it is fair to accept his answer. wish i could accept more than one answer